# Why is it bad practice to not fill the dependency array with all dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I've been looking around without finding any concrete answer, so I thought I'd ask.

React's `useEffect` famously has a dependency array, which tells React when to re-run its function.

- If it's missing, the function is run every re-render.
- If it's empty, the function runs just once.
- If it has dependencies, it re-runs every time one of the dependencies change.

Why is it then that ESLint complains about missing dependencies, if I don't want it to trigger a re-run when most of them change?

Suppose I have a scenario like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    api.send(someUrl, somePayload);
}, [changeMe]);
```

This would be incorrect according to ESLint, as neither `api`, `someUrl`, or `somePayload` are tracked among the dependencies, but I don't want it to trigger every time any of them change, just when `changeMe` changes.

On more than one occasion I've had a `useEffect` loop trigger because it insisted on tracking a function that really didn't need to be tracked to achieve the desired functionality. I'd even wrapped the function in `useCallback` to avoid the reference changing every render, and it still caused an ungodly amount of re-runs.

I know I can disable the ESLint for that line, but the linter is complaining for a reason, I'm just not sure the reason is always warranted.

So what kind of subtle bugs do I risk running into by not filling the dependency array?
What is the real danger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The danger is that one may overlook a dependency that is needed for the code to work as expected. That is, a value changes, but the hook does not run, which may result in a bug.

In your case, you know your code well, so intentionally disabling the warning should be considered good practice.

The linter message even says that you can disable the warning with a code comment, so it should not be considered bad practice to disable warnings intentionally. And you can always add a comment to clarify why a warning is disabled.

I know you are already aware of how to disable linter warnings, but for clarity, this is how I do it:

```
useEffect(() => 
{
    api.send(someUrl, somePayload);
}, 
// Disabled warning about missing dependency since 
// this code is designed to use a single dependency
// eslint-disable-next-line
[changeMe]);
```

I view the linter as a useful tool, but if I want to use a construct that results in a warning, I disable the warning.